# jQuery html not working as expected

Tags: jquery, arrays, getjson

I'm trying to insert new `li` with `img` element inside `ul` based on array, so i'm doing this, but just first item in array is being inserted

```
$.getJSON('/test-url/123').done (data) ->
  $.each data, (index, value) ->
    $('.col ul').html('<li><img src=' + value['m'] + '><li>')
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) replaces all contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('/test-url/123').done (data) ->
  $.each data, (index, value) ->
    $('.col ul').append('<li><img src=' + value['m'] + '><li>')
```

Comment: i've already tried to use `append`, it'll append if there're any `li` tags but i need to first erase there everything then insert

Comment: @user2931706 Then use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) on `$('.col ul')` before your `$.each` call.